# ELMAH File Not Accessible on Local Machine using Host Name

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I can access the elmah.axd file, to view errors, when browsing using the localhost host name (i.e. http://localhost:24425/admin/elmah.axd).

I created a different host name and added it in my host file (to mirror production domain name).  When I browse the site, and force an exception, the exception does get logged (SQL Server) using the prod host name.  However, I am not able to view the elmah.axd file (i.e. http://www.foo.com/admin/elmah.axd).  I get "*HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*"

When I force an exception, using the localhost url, the exception still does get logged in SQL and I am able to browse this file: http://localhost:24425/admin/elmah.axd.  However, I only see exceptions that occur under the localhost url (not the www.foo.com url).

After reviewing SQL, I see errors that happen using localhost with Application "/" and User set to the account I am logged in with.  The errors generated when using www.foo.com have Application set to "/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT" and the User column is blank.

I just need to be able to access the elmah.axd file when using www.foo.com/admin/elmah.axd.  I have set security allowRemoteAccess to "1" in my web.config and have also added the elmah stuff to system.web and system.webServer nodes in my web.config.

I am using Windows Server 2008R2, IIS7.5 and it is a ASP.NET site (set up as a Web Application).

Thanks for any advice given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `elmah.axd` can only be viewed on the local machine (whicj is why using `localhost` works).

You need to configure the web application to [allow remote access](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages).

Comment: I do have this in my web.config, but still not working: <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />

Comment: @obautista - Did you read the whole page? Did you grant access?

Comment: I had not added Authentication and Location stuff in my web.config.  I just added this to my config file.  Now when I attempt to browse www.foo.com/admin/elmah.axd I am redirected to my login page.  I hard coded the login stuff to work, so I could test this.  After logging in, I am redirected to www.foo.com/admin/elmah.axd but still receive "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found:

Comment: @obautista - Have you added the module and handler in the `web.config`?

Comment: I have, what looks likes, the needed info in <configSections>, <elmah>, <httpHandlers> and <httpModules> in <system.web> and also added <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> and <handlers> in <system.webServer>